# Unable to run ubuntu-frame in Hyper-V on Windows 10

Tags: 22.04, windows-10, ubuntu-core, hyper-v

I'm attempting to run ubuntu-frame through Windows virtualization as I have on physical hardware (NUC).  However, for both Ubuntu Core-22 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (server), ubuntu-frame fails to start when running as a virtual system under Hyper-V.  I started with Core-22, but switched to server to provide greater flexibility in troubleshooting and resolution options.

For reference, here is how I am deploying each.

For Core-22, I'm using WSL2 + qemu-img (qemu-utils) to convert the default img to vhdx then manually creating the virtual machine.

```
qemu-img convert ubuntu-core-22-amd64.img -O vhdx -o subformat=dynamic ubuntu-core-22-amd64.vhdx
```

For Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I'm using Multipass + cloud-init

```
multipass launch -n "ubuntu-kiosk" -m 4G -c 4 -d 20G --cloud-init ubuntu-kiosk.yaml 22.04
```

Both core and server instances are successfully installed and I can SSH to each.  However, when installing ubuntu-frame (adding daemon=true for server), VT 4 shows a black screen with a blinking cursing in the top left corner.  Upon inspection ubuntu-frame has exited.  I suspect the issue is related to the hypervisor virtual graphics adapter not being natively supported but I'm struggling to understand how to resolve it. Seems like the ability to run in Hyper-V would have been experienced before.

When I inspect the logs on the NUC I see the following:

```
2023-10-12T19:01:17Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1114]: [2023-10-12 19:01:17.379684] <information> gbm-kms: DRM device details:
2023-10-12T19:01:17Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1114]: [2023-10-12 19:01:17.379725] <information> gbm-kms: /dev/dri/card0: using driver i915 [Intel Graphics] (version: 1.6.0 driver date: 20201103)
```

When I inspect the logs under the virtual instances of core and server, I see the following:

```
2023-10-12T20:29:59Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[2803]: [2023-10-12 20:29:59.056802] <information> eglstream: Failed to query DRM node for EGLDevice: Failed to determine DRM device node path from EGLDevice: EGL_BAD_PARAMETER (0x300c)
2023-10-12T20:29:59Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[2803]: [2023-10-12 20:29:59.056812] < - debug - > eglstream: EGLDeviceEXTs found, but none are suitable for Mir
2023-10-12T20:29:59Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[2803]: [2023-10-12 20:29:59.056817] <information> mirserver: (Unsupported by system environment)
2023-10-12T20:29:59Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[2803]: [2023-10-12 20:29:59.056822] <information> mirserver: Found display driver: mir:gbm-kms (version 2.15.0)
2023-10-12T20:29:59Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[2803]: [2023-10-12 20:29:59.056945] <information> gbm-kms: Unsupported: No DRM devices detected
2023-10-12T20:29:59Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[2803]: [2023-10-12 20:29:59.056989] <information> mirserver: (Unsupported by system environment)
2023-10-12T20:29:59Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[2803]: [2023-10-12 20:29:59.057027] <information> mirserver: Found display driver: mir:x11 (version 2.15.0)
2023-10-12T20:29:59Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[2803]: [2023-10-12 20:29:59.057045] <information> mirserver: (Unsupported by system environment)
2023-10-12T20:29:59Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[2803]: ERROR: ./src/server/graphics/default_configuration.cpp(233): Throw in function virtual const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<mir::graphics::DisplayPlatform> >& mir::DefaultServerConfiguration::the_display_platforms()
2023-10-12T20:29:59Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[2803]: Dynamic exception type: boost::wrapexcept<std::runtime_error>
2023-10-12T20:29:59Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[2803]: std::exception::what: Exception while creating graphics platform
2023-10-12T20:29:59Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[2803]: ERROR: ./src/server/graphics/platform_probe.cpp(190): Throw in function std::vector<std::pair<mir::graphics::SupportedDevice, std::shared_ptr<mir::SharedLibrary> > > {anonymous}::modules_for_device({anonymous}::ModuleType, const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<mir::SharedLibrary> >&, const mir::options::ProgramOption&, const std::shared_ptr<mir::ConsoleServices>&)
2023-10-12T20:29:59Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[2803]: Dynamic exception type: boost::wrapexcept<std::runtime_error>
2023-10-12T20:29:59Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[2803]: std::exception::what: Failed to find any platforms for current system
2023-10-12T20:29:59Z systemd[1]: snap.ubuntu-frame.daemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2023-10-12T20:29:59Z systemd[1]: snap.ubuntu-frame.daemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The goal is to provide a development playground for Ubuntu-Core with ubuntu-frame.  Falling back to the server might be ok for this purpose or even updating the kernel snap for dev purposes only.  I'm hoping, since this is Hyper-V, that it would be easy enough to duplicate.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I found several articles from 2021 calling out that Hyper-V DRM display drivers were to be included in Linux 5.14 kernel. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS kernel is 5.15 but clearly didn’t include the expected Hyper-V support. I assumed the easiest approach would be to upgrade to the HWE kernel for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS which is 6.2. After making that change, ubuntu-frame launches as expected.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04
```